# Ruby On Rails. Change controller's variable through view and render updated view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm very beginner in RoR and even in web-programming. So I guess my question is so easy for many developers!

I'm implementing simple weeks calendar, it should have day's names and two "buttons" - 'next week' and 'previous week'. That's all for beginning!

I have controller with index action:

```
    def index

      @today = Date::today
      @monday = @today.beginning_of_week
      @sunday = @today.end_of_week

      @currentweek = @monday..@sunday    
   end
```

and two other actions:

```
  def go_next_week
      @monday = @sunday + 1
      @sunday = @monday.end_of_week
  end

  def go_prev_week
      @sunday = @monday - 1
      @monday = @sunday.beginning_of_week
  end
```

index view code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="data">
    <thead>
    <tr class="month-names">      
      <td><%= form_tag(work_days_go_prev_week_path, method: "get") do %>
            <%= submit_tag(l(("workdays_show_prev" + period).to_sym)) %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td><%= render :partial => 'days_names_header' %></td>
      <td><%= form_tag(work_days_go_next_week_path, method: "get") do %>
            <%= submit_tag(l(("workdays_show_next" + period).to_sym)) %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the routes file:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'work_days/go_next_week'            ,:to => 'work_days#go_next_week',           via: [:get]
  match 'work_days/go_prev_week'            ,:to => 'work_days#go_prev_week',           via: [:get]
  match 'work_days/(:action(/:id))',via: [:get], :controller => 'work_days'
end
```

The main goal on that stage in short terms is:

- Controller has a Date variables 'monday','sunday' and Range
  'currentweek'
- Index view shows table of days according that    variables
- Index view has 2 "buttons": 'next week' and 'previous    week'
- Clicking on this buttons should change Controller's    variables
- Index view should "refresh" with changed Controller's    variables

This code isn't working. I got such error in log when clicking on 'Previous month' button:

> Started GET
>   "/work_days/go_prev_week?tf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Previous+week" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-09 14:00:27 +0600 Processing by WorkDaysController#go_prev_week as HTML Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓","commit"=>"Previous week"} Current user: admin (id=1)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like that you want to have the same controller action and view but only with other dates.

If that's the case I would recommend you something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_date

  def index
  end

  private

  def set_date
    if params[:week].present? && params[:year].present?
      @today = Date.commercial(params[:year].to_i, params[:week].to_i)
    end

    @today ||= Date::today # <= Just use date today if it's not set already

    @monday = @today.beginning_of_week
    @sunday = @monday - 1
    @monday = @sunday.beginning_of_week
  end
end
```

**The routes:**

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'calendar' => 'my_controller#index', as: :index_action
end
```

Then you can add next/previous links to your view like this:

```
<%= link_to "Next", index_action_path(year: @today.year, week: @today.cweek + 1) %>
<%= link_to "Previous", index_action_path(year: @today.year, week: @today.cweek - 1) %>
```

I haven't tested this implementation yet but it should work. You should add tests anyway.

But you should definitively check the parameters if they are correct. For example if they are in the range of 1 to 52 for week and so on. Otherwise it will raise an exception if the week is out of range.

Try also to not put logic into the view but in helper methods.

I hope this helps and happy coding. :)

Comment: At first look it works! At least weeks in calendar is changing now! Thanks, Tobias!
And since it's just a beginning of "project" I'm sure that there will be not only one more question from me ))))

Answer (score 3):

> I'm very beginner in RoR and even in web-programming.

Welcome!

---

Your problem is that you're populating your controller action with `@instance_variables` which are reliant on each other:

```
def go_next_week
  @monday = @sunday + 1           # needs @sunday
  @sunday = @monday.end_of_week   # needs @monday
end
```

In old school programming, that would have probably lead to an unrecognized reference error or perhaps a stack overflow error, typically due to infinite [recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion).

The error confirms this:

> undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

`Ruby` is different than most other languages in that it assigns undeclared variables to the `NilClass` object. This makes it very difficult for developers to determine the error - basically if you receive `undefined method for NilClass`, it's that you've not declared your variable.

--

The fix would be to get the data you're trying to manipulate into the instance of the class. This can be achieved with a [`before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) filter:

```
#app/controllers/work_days_controller.rb
class WorkDaysController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_dates

   def index
      #@today, @monday, @sunday will be available in here.
   end

   private

   def set_dates
      @today = Date::today
      @monday = @today.beginning_of_week
      @sunday = @today.end_of_week
   end
end
```

---

You could also improve your routes to make use of the [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) directive:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :work_days do
   get :go_next_week, on: :collection
   get :go_prev_week, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I supposed that sunday and monday variables are initialized in index action and then I may use it in actions go_next_week and etc. Get I missed some theory of this?

Comment: Yep - `index` is not being invoked when you call another action. This means that `@monday` & `@sunday` are not present, a big problem. You'd be best setting them explicitly with `before_action` to make sure they're available to all actions that you need.

Comment: So instance variables only presents in current action? Not it whole Controller class?
Then how to pass from index view value of monday(sunday) variable to increment\decrement week in action go_next(prev)_week?

Comment: You can use the `before_action` code I put above to make the variables accessible to the specific action. When you invoke a class through Rails, it's only the action instance method which is loaded. Whilst you can call the other methods, it's not advisable. Thus, if you wanted to keep certain data available for a number of actions, you'd set them with an instance method in the `before_action` callback -- which would make the data available as required.

Comment: Thanks for info about `before_action` callback and instance variables logic.
But next problem is passing value of instance variable from `form_tag` to action 'go_next_week'. As I think I could get some `params[]` in action, but I don't understand what and how to pass from `form_tag` to `params[] `of action.

Comment: Good one, I suggest to follow this answer.Thanks Rich Peck

Comment: I suppose your code is able to change only to 1 week back and forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably initialize these instance variables in a `before_action`.

So for example:

```
class MyController < ActionController
  before_action :set_dates

  def index
    # ... Your index implementation
  end

  def go_next_week
    @monday = @sunday + 1
    @sunday = @monday.end_of_week
  end

  def go_prev_week
    @sunday = @monday - 1
    @monday = @sunday.beginning_of_week
  end

  private

  def set_dates
    @today = Date::today
    @monday = @today.beginning_of_week
    @sunday = @today.end_of_week

    @currentweek = @monday..@sunday
  end
end
```

In this way the dates will be initialized in every single action. But be careful! This this implementation above just allows to go one week back of further. To make this work with every week you have to provide a `param` with the current week for example.

I hope this helps and if you need more information you are welcome. :)

Comment: Why `@sunday` variable isn't initialized in go_next_week? I supposed that when occurs first call of action 'index' (when view is loading) `@sunday` is initializing.
Or index action and go_next_week actions is call for different instances?

Comment: In above answers I got clear understanding of instance variables logic. But I still don't see how to pass `sunday` value from `form_tag` to go_next_week(sunday) action.

Comment: Ok I understand now what you mean. These are two other controller actions not just methods which are called in the index action. I will update my answer.

Comment: Tobias, it partially helps (
As I understand to render index view with updated variables I have to put `render index` in the end of method go_next_week. Is that right? If so, I got another error: `ArgumentError ('Tue, 01 Dec 2015..Thu, 31 Dec 2015' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.)`
Is it issue with `currentweek` Range variable in index view or what?

Comment: You should probably change your implementation if you want the same view but only the dates changed. I will post another answer how I would achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using @monday in the action go_prev_week,you are not calculating @monday inside the method,@monday is an instance variable its by default value is nil.

You have two way to resolve this issue -

First -

```
  def go_prev_week
     index
     @sunday = @monday - 1
     @monday = @sunday.beginning_of_week
  end
```

Second  - calculate @monday

```
  def go_prev_week
     @today = Date::today
     @monday = @today.beginning_of_week
     @sunday = @monday - 1
     @monday = @sunday.beginning_of_week
  end
```

You have to do same thing in the action ***go_next_week***

Comment: If I use variable monday in index action, then I can't use it in some other actions?

Comment: you could not access. either you have to call the index method or you need to calculate